# Is MobiForms for Android worth investigating?

Tags: java, android, rad

I'm working my way through the NotePad tutorial, and that's all fine - I'm not a Java programmer but it's close enough to C# (or vice versa) to make it easy to pick up. I'm surprised that there aren't any RAD tools for Android apart from Mobiforms. Is there anyone out there with experience of Mobiforms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, RAD tools like mobiforms give you a "lowest common denominator" development environment. While mobiforms for android does support some of the hardware features (GPS, camera), which puts it a step ahead of most traditional smartphone RAD environments, it doesn't give you complete hardware access, may or may not track support of new hardware and android implementations, and may not give you an application that looks and feels like a native android application.

Note that these issues are common across RAD technology, and are especially true is a very diverse mobile market today, where the features, form factors, resolution, etc are differing week to week.

Ultimately, in my opinion, working within the android development environments is going to provide a better experience, today.

Comment: Yes since I asked the question I've started using Appcelerator Titanium.